# Not able to manipulate map functions in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hit an api available at [covid19 api](https://api.covid19api.com/summary)  [ you can see directly , click it ] but I am not able to map through the state. 
I tried browsing the questions and still didn't find it .

my code in app.js is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import api from '../api/covidapi'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                  country : 'Please Enter the country',
                  active_cases : 'No country found',
                  countries : [],
                  errorMessage : '',
                  isLoading : false,
              };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    const response = await api.get('/summary');
    console.log('data loaded   = >  ', response);

       console.log(response.data.Countries.length) // giving 247
       console.log('countries ', response.data.Countries) //lists all countries {....},{...}...

      this.setState({countries:response.data.Countries})

      // console.log('global end')
      this.setState({
          totalConfirmed : response.data.Global.TotalConfirmed,
      })
    } //component did mount ended.

      onSearchSubmit = async (country) =>{
            console.log(country)

            try {

              const response = 
                 await api.get(`/live/country/${country}/status/confirmed`)

      this.setState({country:country, active_cases:response.data[6].Active})      
                }

            catch(e) {
                    this.setState({errorMessage : "Country Doesn't exist or misspelled"})
               }  
    }; //onsearch submit ended.

  render() {

  return (
     <div>  
        <div className="container">
             <p style={{textAlign:'center',
                   backgroundColor:'green',            
                   color:'white',
                   width:'97%',margin:'auto',
                   padding:'24px',
                   marginTop:'12px',}}>
              Total confirmed as of now is <span> :  </span>   
                    <span style={{color : 'red'}} > 
                            {this.state.totalConfirmed}
                    </span>
          </p>
          <SearchBar onSubmit = {this.onSearchSubmit}/>
      </div>   

    <div className="container">
            <h2 className="bg bg-primary" style={{marginBottom:'0px', 
                      textAlign:'center',marginTop:'15px',
                      padding:'10px'}}>Covid19 Cases In single Country
             </h2>

   <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Country</th>
                  <th>Acitve Cases</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>

         <tbody>
                <tr>
                      <td>{this.state.country}</td>
                      <td>{ this.state.active_cases}</td>
                </tr>  
         </tbody> 
</table>

</div>

  <br />
  <hr />

<div className="container">
     <div style={{textAlign:'center',color:'red',fontWeight:'bold'}}>
      </div>

      <h2 className="bg bg-primary" style={{marginBottom:'0px',
          textAlign:'center', padding:'10px'}}> 
          Covid19 Cases Worldwide
     </h2>

   <table className="table table-striped table-hover table-dark">
            <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>S.N</th>
                    <th>Country Name</th>
                    <th>Confirmed Cases</th>
                    <th> Total Deaths</th>
                    <th>Total Recovered</th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>     

     {  
           Object.keys(this.state.countries).map((country) => (          
            <tr>   
                  <td>{country}</td> 
                  <td>........</td>
                  <td>........</td>
                  <td> ........</td>
                  <td>............</td>    
           </tr> 
         ))
      }  

          </tbody>
    </table> 
  </div>              
</div>
  ); 
  }
}

export default App;
```

and covidapi.js code is

```
    import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL :'https://api.covid19api.com'
})
```

The problem is in this section of the code in app.js

```
{  
       Object.keys(this.state.countries).map((country) => (          
        <tr>   
              <td>{country}</td> 
              <td>........</td>
              <td>........</td>
              <td> ........</td>
              <td>............</td>    
       </tr> 
     ))
  }
```

I am not able to map through countries in my state , I think there is 
  problem with the Objects and array.

when  Render the country that is passed in map it return the integer value like  1,2,3 .... and not able to get other values. 
  Response in the console looks like this

[image]

What I am trying is to display the all the countries list to the table whenever the application loads.

Comment: I think adding a codesandbox link can get much much better help.

Comment: Please post actual code, not pictures of code

Comment: Might be but still I know it's pretty basic and just posted the photo.

Comment: NO, if you post codesandbox, I can solve your problem in one minute.

Comment: @O.o should i delete it and repost ?

Comment: Just edit, you can add a codesandbox and don't remove console results. ;)

Comment: Why would you use `this.state.countries[country]` when you are already iterating.
It should be just `country` inside your first `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.state.countries` directly without `Object.keys()` (It is an array already), and use the properties inside each item as follows:

```
{
  this.state.contries.map(item => {
    return(
        <tr>
            <td> { item.Country } </td>
            <td> { item.totalConfirmed } </td>
            ... // Other tds
        </tr>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  it works now . Basically the problem was to recognize data and format in developer console.